# ToolTip window gets blinking when changing the window position

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, interop, popupwindow

I am developing a Popup control which will be shown as ToolTip while hovering the integrated controls and i have achieved this.

I have changed the position of the window using **SetWindowPos** method of **user32 dll** and the position is changing successfully.

Before changing the Tooltip window position, normally it is shown BottomRight of the cursor position.

My issue is, when i change the position of window which doesn't intersect the region of default window position (BottomRight), it is working fine. **But when i change the position of window, which any area of the window intersects in the range of default position of window. Then the window is blinking and the popup is not properly shown.**

Here is the code part which i used to change the position of window in Bottom Center of cursor position.

```
point = Cursor.Position;
point.X -= this.Size.Width / 2;
WindowsAPI.SetWindowPos(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, point.X, point.Y, 0, 0, SWP_MOVE);
```

using above code will intersect half of window region with default window region.

Please anyone suggest me, why changing the position which intersects in default position causes blinking of window and improper showing.

**Edit for workaround:**
I have noticed that window procedure is repeatedly gets fired that why window is blinked. When i changed the Y position of window by **point.Y+=1;** blinking issue resolved.

i think the cursor position placed in Popup window results in again showing the window which caused blinking. Can anyone confirm this behavior? If not, please correct me.

Regards,Amal Raj.